# What misunderstanding does this refer to?

Tags: confidence-interval, frequentist

The confidence interval entry in Wikipedia lists a number of common misunderstandings about confidence intervals. One of these is described as follows:

> A confidence interval is not a definitive range of plausible values for the sample parameter, though it is often heuristically taken as a range of plausible values.

Do you know what misunderstanding this vague description is referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure what definition of "plausible" is behind this, but in principle one could *define* the term plausible so that the statement becomes true (omitting the word "definitive" in there which may not do any good), and although there are ways to criticise that, I'd say it's not the worst definition of "plausible" that you can have. (Try to give a better one if you think differently.) Obviously it will be relative to the confidence level and possibly other choices.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I am trying to identify what the common misunderstanding is since the description is so vague. If it cannot be identified by experts then it needs to be deleted.  If it can be identified then, if valid, it needs to be edited for greater clarity. As a start, surely the adjective 'sample' in the phrase 'sample parameter' is a mistake in the context of a fixed unknown parameter, so that word at least should be deleted. Regarding your specific point about the definition of plausibility, I am not sure that can explain which is the misunderstanding it refers to.

Comment: @ChristianHennig  (cont) The dictionary definition of plausible is: "(of an argument or statement) seeming reasonable or probable." In this context, probable suggests probability, but that common misunderstanding was already dealt with earlier in the Wikipedia list of common misunderstandings.  If we drop the word 'definitive' as you suggest then we are left with: " A (particular) confidence interval is not a range of reasonable values for the parameter, though ......" Surely that is false since in many (but not all) cases, that is what a confidence provides.

Comment: Personally I could well live without having this on Wikipedia. At the very least it is underexplained and intransparent. Wikipedia is no top authority when it comes to statistics. I'm not saying it's plain wrong, I can imagine elaborations that make it right or wrong, but for sure it's not clear as it stands (which of course justifies your question, just don't take this as authoritative statement).

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks Christian for your valuable feedback. Yes, I have found Wikipedia unreliable on a few statistics topics. Before proceeding further, I will wait for a while to see what further responses my question elicits.

Answer (score 4):

I find the term *set estimator* (cf. $\rm [I]$) more apt than the conventional confidence set (interval). Let $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb R^n); \mathbf \Theta\subset \mathbb R^n.$ Set estimators are simply the measurable functions for all $\theta\in\mathbf \Theta$ as $C:\mathscr X\mapsto \mathcal C$ defined by $\mathbf x\to \mathbb I_{C(\mathbf x)}(\theta).$ The set $C(\mathbf x) $ is thus the random quantity - the probability to *cover* $\theta$ is $\Pr[\theta\in C(\mathbf x)].$ It is clear that $C(\mathbf x) $ is not providing a set of $\theta$s that are plausible.

> [It] doesn't say anything about how likely $\theta$ is once [the sample $\mathbf x$] is observed.

So, to assert the confidence set/interval is "a definitive range of plausible values for the sample parameter" is misleading.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I] $ Fundamentals of Mathematical Statistics, *Steffen Lauritzen,* CRC Press, $2023, $ sec. $6.1, $ p. $135.$

Comment: I appreciate this measurable function perspective of confidence intervals (+1).

Comment: "It is clear that C(x) is not providing a set of θs that are plausible." No, that is not clear, but perhaps I am not understanding your way of describing confidence interval procedures. Are you able to explain using the conventional approach with an assumed statistical model indexed by a fixed parameter $\theta$ and with random variable X, a random sample x, and a confidence set  C(X) such that, say, Pr[$\theta$ in C(X)] = 0.999 for all $\theta$? [The observed confidence set/interval is C(x).}

Comment: Very well. But first, tell me what you understand by Pr[θ
 in C(X)] = 0.999.

Comment: The whole thing hinges on how you explain this. In any case $C(\mathbf x) $ isn't providing a set of $\theta$s that are in tandem with the model. The frequentist interpretation is clear in stating that $C(\mathbf x) $ only  covers  $\theta, ~99.9~\%$ of the times.

Comment: @User1865345 As far as I can tell, my views do not differ from the standard frequentist understanding of confidence intervals. Yet I and others have not been able to identify which common misunderstanding of the frequentist confidence interval approach is being described by the Wikipedia quote (see my comments to Christian Hennig above). If it can be identified, and if it is valid, then the Wikipedia entry can be edited for clarity to remove the vagueness.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt, I surely agree with you and Henning that it could have been framed in a better and clear way but imo it is not that vague to elicit any meaningful substance from it: the confidence set(s) doesn't provide you a set of parameter(s) which is (are) likely to be the tentative one(s); rather it's a random set that has a certain probability that it covers the parameter which is unknown. See, for instance, the quoted line.

Comment: And yes, again I agree with you and Henning (and probably others) that while Wikipedia can be handy and go to reference, it shouldn't be used for formal learning or gaining conceptual knowledge altogether.

Comment: @user1865345 Your Lauritzen quote seems to be saying that there is no useful probability attached to the observed confidence interval. That’s OK. That’s why Neyman used a different word to distinguish between the pre-sample procedure and a post-sample outcome. If I draw a random sample to calculate a 99.9% confidence interval for $\theta$ under some model, and the observed confidence interval is [3.6, 5.4] then with this model this interval is a range of reasonable estimates for the unknown fixed parameter.

Comment: @user1865345 (cont.) Under this model, either $\theta$ is covered by [3.6, 5.4] or an unlucky rare event has occurred (note the past tense). In this sense, I could report using the communal ‘we’ that “Under this model, we are 99.9% confident that $\theta$ lies in the interval [3.6, 5.4].” Note that such confidence claims would be less meaningful if the unconditional procedure has poor conditional properties (examples of which are the usual sources of ‘counter-examples’ of the confidence interval approach), in which case a conditional confidence interval procedure might be used.

Comment: $[3.6, 5.4]$ would either cover the parameter or not. Probability is either $1$ or $0.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148445/discussion-between-graham-bornholt-and-user1865345).